# Self-join in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, self-join

I am trying to find duplicated data based on xCorelationIDon a collection as mentioned below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "627jhjhghgf5251c87klkjkj601aee", 
    "creationDate" : "2022-05-12T17:16:31.788+0000", 
    "modifiedDate" : "2022-05-12T17:16:43.062+0000", 
    "claimNumber" : "Q030NEE01932", 
    "xCorrelationId" : "b25a19ad-7816-4288-a0d9-becc0ac0a5db", 
    "modifiedBy" : "12311684", 
    "events" : [{
        "abc":1
    }
    ], 
    "_class" : "com.xyaxdd"
},
{ 
    "_id" : "627d40f05251c87c3f601aee", 
    "creationDate" : "2022-09-12T17:16:31.788+0000", 
    "modifiedDate" : "2022-09-12T17:16:43.062+0000", 
    "claimNumber" : "Q030NEE0jhjhj", 
    "xCorrelationId" : "b25a19ad-7816-4288-a0d9-becc0ac0a5db", 
    "modifiedBy" : "456311684", 
    "events" : [{
        "xyz":3455
    }
    ], 
    "_class" : "com.AuditRecord"
}
```

I have the following query which works fine but The piece where I am stuck is on modifiedBy. Column modifiedBy should correspond for the record with max(modifiefDate).

```
db.audit.aggregate([
    {$group : { "_id": "$xCorrelationId", "count": { $sum: 1 },
        events: {$push: "$events"},
        creationDate: { $min: "$creationDate" }, modifiedDate: { $max: "$modifiedDate" },claimNumber:{$first: "$claimNumber"}, _class:{$first: "$_class"}
         },
        
    },
    {$match: {"_id" :{ $ne : null } , "count" : {$gt: 1} } },
    {$sort: {count: -1}},
    {$project: {"xCorrelationId" : "$_id", "_id" : 0, count: 1,
        events:{
          $reduce: {
            input: '$events',
            initialValue: [],
            in: {$concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this']}
          }
        },
        creationDate: 1, modifiedDate: 1, claimNumber: 1, _class: 1
    } },
    
],
{allowDiskUse:true});
```

I think below self-join SQL query should get me the result but I am not able to find how can I accomplish in Mongodb

```
SELECT modifiedBy
FROM dpr_audit_record s
   JOIN (SELECT MAX(modifiedDate) AS md, _id FROM dpr_audit_record GROUP BY xCorrelationId) max
      ON s._id = max._id
```

Outcome based on above shared collection should be

````
{ 
  "_id" : "627jhjhghgf5251c87klkjkj601aee", 
  "creationDate" : "2022-05-12T17:16:31.788+0000", 
  "modifiedDate" : "2022-09-12T17:16:43.062+0000", 
  "claimNumber" : "Q030NEE01932", 
  "xCorrelationId" : "b25a19ad-7816-4288-a0d9-becc0ac0a5db", 
  "modifiedBy" : "456311684", 
  "events" : [{
      "abc":1
  },{
    "xyz":3455
  }
  ], 
  "_class" : "com.xyaxdd"
}```
````

Comment: What version of the database will you be doing this on?

Comment: Please provide your requested output for this case

Comment: How do you choose which `claimNumber` and `_class`  you want? using `$first` without sorting before is not deterministic and will return different results...

Comment: @user20042973 4.4.15

Comment: @nimrodserok I have updated the question asked above with expected outcome..

Idea is get claimNumber and _class 's first value from the group having same XcorelationId field

Comment: Why is `claimNumber` "Q030NEE01932" first? You did not used a `$sort` stage, if you run the same query tomorrow on a real db, it may be "Q030NEE0jhjhj" as well. Is it OK, or do you need "Q030NEE01932" to be in the result? If so, why? In other words, is the sorting order of fields that are not `modifiedBy` important?

Comment: Ok.. Can you let me know how can I implement sorting within a group of same xCorelationId? Lets just say sort by DESC creationDate

Comment: sorting within a group of related xCorelationId shouldn't affect modifiedBy field.. I need to take modifiedBy value for that data set with max value of modifiedDate. For example, if there are 10 datasets within a group of related xCorelationId and 5th dataset has max date for modifiedDate then I need to take modifiedBy value for that 5th dataset..